# Is it possible that my MBP (running Yosemite) can remote turn on my iPhone 4S's (running iOS 8.1) personal hotspot?

Tags: iphone, wifi, macos, ios

I heard somewhere (urgh! not a good start to a question) that with Yosemite + iOS 8.1, i can now turn on my iPhone personal hotspot remotely, and then try and connect to it (assuming the iPhone is *near*).

Is this correct? what's this feature called and how can i do this?

Currently, I always have to goto the general settings on my phone and then manually turn on the personal hotspot. This works perfectly (i'm posting this via my 3G connection, right now).

cheers for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature I'm after is called: **Instant Hotspot**

It seems like an iPhone 4S *cannot* do this feature. From [what people are saying](http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/26/yosemite-ios-8-how-to-set-up-and-use-instant-hotspot/), it's an iPhone 5 or newer. [Apple also confirm this](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204689).

Sad.Panda :(